# STL container find_or_create()

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Is there some sort of STL facility for doing a `find_or_create()` on STL containers?

E.g. in the case of unordered_map, I frequently find myself needing to retrieve some value and create it if no value exists. There are plenty of functions for conditionally inserting into a map, but all of them result in creating a new value right away, even if one is already present in the map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {
        A() = default;

        A(std::string_view method) {
                std::cout << "Created via " << method << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
        std::unordered_map<int, A> m{
                {0, A{}}
        };

        // Get a reference to m[0]; create it if it doesn't exist
        // Key 0 is already in the map, so these calls *should* do little work
        auto &val1 = *m.insert(std::make_pair(0, A{"insert"})).first;
        auto &val2 = *m.emplace(0, A{"emplace"}).first;
        auto &val3 = *m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                        std::make_tuple(0),
                        std::make_tuple("piecewise construct")).first;
        auto &val4 = *m.try_emplace(0, A{"try_emplace"}).first;
        auto &val5 = (m[0] = A{"operator[]"});

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Created via insert
Created via emplace
Created via piecewise construct
Created via try_emplace
Created via operator[]
```

In the event that object `A` is costly to create (takes a long time to construct, acquires system resources, etc.) these unnecessary creations can be undesirable. This often leads me to create a template like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A {
        A() = default;

        A(std::string_view method) {
                std::cout << "Created via " << method << std::endl;
        }
};

template<class Map, class OnCreate>
typename Map::mapped_type &find_or_create(Map &map, const typename Map::key_type &key, const OnCreate &on_create) {
        auto it = map.find(key);
        if (it == map.end())
                it = map.emplace(key, on_create(key)).first;
        return it->second;
}

int main() {
        std::unordered_map<int, A> m;

        // Get a reference to m[0]; create it if it doesn't exist
        auto &val1 = find_or_create(m, 0, [](const int &) { return A{"find_or_create"}; });
        auto &val2 = find_or_create(m, 0, [](const int &) { return A{"never created"}; });
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Created via find_or_create
```

Is there a better (i.e. simpler) way to achieve this via STL, or is a template like this one the way to go?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk of all the containers as if they're the same, they are not.  Pick one.

Comment: Doesn't `try_emplace()` already do this? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) says that this function does **nothing** if the map already contains that key, which suggests that the object is never constructed and destroyed in that case. Of course you'd have to use `emplace()` *correctly* to avoid it internally move-constructing the actual object to insert from the object you already constructed as an argument to `emplace()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try_emplace` is what you want. Your problem is that you are deliberately *constructing* an `A`, instead of passing the *arguments* to the constructor, which it may or may not use to construct the `A`.

What you want is this:

```
auto &val4 = *m.try_emplace(0, "try_emplace").first;
```

Your find-or-create function would be useful if you can't create the object via constructor call (ie: instances get created via factory functions or whatever).

Comment: Yep that makes sense, forgot that try_emplace works that way! My most recent use case for find_or_create was for working with something like std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<A>>. Since calling unique_ptr's constructor requires creating an A instance anyway, I suppose I'll stick with find_or_create for that case